# "Paste" sometimes not available in Flutter TextFormField on Android

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, toolbar, paste

Some of our Android users complained that they can't paste text from their notes app into our app.

I can get it back to work for some time if I do weird things like open our app, copy something from our textfield, paste it into another note app and then the pasting function suddenly works.

I noticed that the Text Editing function from the keyboard also doesn't recognize that somethiing is in the clipboard while it does recognize it in Google Notes.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVKoB.jpg [1]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNm5O.jpg [2]

```html
TextFormField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          minLines: 3,
          maxLines: null,
          autofocus: true,
          onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
            mood.text = value;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              mood.text = value;
            });
          },
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 18),
          cursorColor: Colors.white70,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusColor: Colors.white70,
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Color(0xFF1F202A),
            hintMaxLines: 3,
            hintText: locator.get<Translation>().add_mood_screen_textfield,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 18),
          ))
```

Comment: Did you ever get any progress on this? Almost two years later and we are also having users reporting something very similar sounding

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing for "Paste" text into your Flutter app might be related to the specific setup of the TextFormField. Ensure that you have enabled the paste property and set the controller property correctly.

```
TextEditingController moodController = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
  controller: moodController,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  minLines: 3,
  maxLines: null,
  autofocus: true,
  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
    // Handle field submission if needed
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    // Handle field changes if needed
  },
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 18),
  cursorColor: Colors.white70,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    focusColor: Colors.white70,
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Color(0xFF1F202A),
    hintMaxLines: 3,
    hintText: locator.get<Translation>().add_mood_screen_textfield,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 18),
  ),
  enableInteractiveSelection: true, // Ensure text is selectable
  enableSuggestions: true, // Enable text suggestions
  readOnly: false, // Allow editing
  onTap: () {
    // Handle tap if needed
  },
);
```